# How to build statically linked application with PIC enabled static libraries

Tags: unix, libraries

I've a statically linked application (sample.a) and I want to build it with a third party library(third-party-lib.a) which is PIC enabled. Note that the third party library is NOT a shared library. It is a PIC enabled static library.

Can anyone please suggest how do I do this?

I tried linking my library with a third party library like we usually link static libraries but it gives me an error:

/usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a(stack_chk_fail_local.oS): In function `__stack_chk_fail_local':
(.text+0x10): undefined reference to`__stack_chk_fail'

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using **nm** to try finding the symbols involved. Good idea would be also to check if there isn't any #define you need to take care of or similar. By itself, a PIC-enabled static library shouldn't change anything in linking, as long as you compile the rest of the program with -fPIC as well.

Altogether, it doesn't seem to me like something caused by PIC settings. Did you per chance built the code previously with dynamic libraries, and only now switched to static? That could explain missing some bits of configuration involved, among other things.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Our code is not compiled with -fPIC. Only the third party library that we are trying to build with is -fPIC enabled but it is not a shared object. It is a -fPIC enabled static library. Are you suggesting that we need to compile our code with -fPIC? Is it the only way?

Comment: From my understanding, you shouldn't need to recompile with -fPIC (as static libraries shouldn't have the addresses set in place at all), but I'm not sure about actual mechanism used by the linker.

Comment: Thanks.. Please let me know if you have any other info.. Anyone aware of this?